# org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to run some JUnit tests on my program and I keep getting this exception in the title. I'm a noobie at this kind of thing in programming and I barely know what I'm doing. I've tried changing some of the dependency versions, adding some I might be missing, and it's just error after error.

I'm trying to test the PCBuild DAO's getById method with JUnit. Let me know if I'm missing any info. I would have loved to post more relevant code, but I keep getting hit with the "this looks like spam" filter, so sorry, I tried.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hardwareViewer</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">student</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping class="entity.User"/>
        <mapping class="entity.PcBuild"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="(url I can't post here)"
      xsi:schemaLocation="(same here apparently)">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.matc.entjava.hardwareviewer</groupId>
  <artifactId>hardwareviewer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hardwareviewer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit-vintage-version>4.12.0</junit-vintage-version>
    <javax.version>7.0</javax.version>
    <mysql-version>5.1.39</mysql-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <log4j-version>2.10.0</log4j-version>
    <jupiter-version>5.0.0</jupiter-version>
    <junit-platform-runner-version>1.0.0</junit-platform-runner-version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.19</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
    <hibernate-core-version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate-core-version>
    <hibernate-c3p0-version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate-c3p0-version>
    <javax-persistence-version>2.2</javax-persistence-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-vintage-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${jupiter-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax-persistence-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  next 2 dependencies are for log4j  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-c3p0-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>hardwareviewer</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
              <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

PcBuild DAO class

```
package persistence;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import entity.PcBuild;

public class PcBuildDao {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryProvider.getSessionFactory();

    public PcBuild getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        PcBuild pcBuild = session.get(PcBuild.class, id);
        session.close();
        return pcBuild;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdatePcBuild(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public int insert(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        int id = 0;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        id = (int) session.save(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void delete(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error message is clear. You have invalid hibernate.cfg.xml witch can't be unmarshaled with jaxb. Look if You have some bad symbol on first place in your xml file. Often if you copy xml from some quelle with content you get some odd symbols

Comment: It's not clear though? I looked and looked and there's no weird symbols or anything at the beginning of hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Set a break point where the exception is thrown and try to understand what happens. Most likely, you simply have a small typo somewhere.